# Does the amount of consumed ATB matter for abilities that consume the entire ATB gauge?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

In  Final Fantasy 7 Remake, some of Barret's abilities have a unique usage that differs from most abilities. These abilities are

- Focused Shot
- Maximum Fury
- Point Blank

The difference in these abilities is that the descriptions state they "consume all ATB". Every other ability requires a blanket 1 or 2 ATB gauges in order to perform. The abilities above can be used as long as there is at least 1 ATB gauge filled.

If I were to execute these abilities, is there any difference in the damage output between consuming 1 ATB gauge or 2 ATB gauges? If so, would using Refocus have any effect (given that Refocus splits the ATB gauge into 3 segments, but the total ATB amount is the same)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes a difference. The more ATB gauge there is, then the more damage they will do.

In the case of maximum fury, it is the duration of the move that is increased, thus outputting more damage over time.

Regarding "Refocus", it doesn't seem to make a difference between 3 bars and 2 bars. So I believe it is accurate to say that damage is based on the amount of ATB guage, and not based on the number or bars. Not that is would be useful anyway because who wants to waste a Limit on Refocus.

Comment: "who wants to waste a Limit on Refocus." -> me :) I use Refocus all the time with Aerith. Being able to cast a high level Prayer more often is very useful during boss battles. Especially on hard mode with Prayer being a command and not a spell; MP is like gold

Comment: I never found my limits would be frequent enough for it to be useful. Having said that, Aeris other limits aren't really that useful anyway so I guess Refocus might be decent on her. Although her 2nd limit is useful for a late game boss on hard, and lots of strats recommend it for the hardest training challenge.